# Datetime displayed using JQuery Timeago

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, timeago

I am trying to display my date using the timeago plugin. This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="container col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 notifications-container">
@{
    foreach (var n in Model.Notifications)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <a href="@n.URL">
                 <div class="container col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-xs-12">
                    <h2>@n.Title</h2>
                    <h5>@n.ShortDescription</h5>
                    <h5 id="date-time"></h5>
                    <h5>
                        <time class="timeago" datetime="@n.Time.ToString("s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)"> @n.Time </time>
                    </h5>
                    <script>

                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $("time.timeago").timeago();
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    }
}
```

It isn't converting my datetime, Not sure if I need to change the format of it so timeago can use it.

Update: I got it working this way and the DateTime passed in this scenario is of type UTC.Now

There is one bug that I have yet to fix which shows that all entries were made about an hour ago even though some of them were a couple of seconds ago..

Comment: What are you getting rendered in `<h5 id="date-time">@n.Time</h5>`

Comment: Each one of these outputs something along the lines of: 16/04/2017 21:09:57

Comment: Do you have more than one `#date-time` rendered on the page?

Comment: Just however many in that list which has 5 right now. I have changed the datetime to UTC instead which might work

Comment: I think that I have the solution but involves adding `momentjs` to your project

Comment: Found a partial solution just now, updated the question to reflect that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to add [momentjs](/questions/tagged/momentjs) to your project as a workaround, because, [timeago](/questions/tagged/timeago) just works with dates in `ISO 8601` format:

You need to change this:

```
<h5 id="date-time">@n.Time</h5>
```

To this:

```
<h5 class="date-time">
 <time class="timeago" datetime="">@n.Time</time>
</h5>
```

And your `javascript` code, to this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dateAux;
  $(".timeago").each(function(i,item){
      dateAux = moment($(item).html(),'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss');
      $(item).attr('datetime',dateAux.toISOString());
  })  
  $("time.timeago").timeago();
});
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jn233dk4/1/

Comment: Do you think think it's possible to change the DateTime to ISO 8601?

Comment: I'm glad to help :)